Не работает валидация формы asp.net
Я делаю учебный проект - блог на asp.net core mvc, у меня есть форма для создания комментариев к постам, я подключаю ее через
@{
     Html.RenderPartial("~/Views/Comments/Create.cshtml", new Comment { PostId = Model.Id });
 }

на страницу поста. Но у меня по непонятным мне причинам не работает валидация формы, код формы:
@model Comment


<div class="card shadow-0 border" style="background-color: #f0f2f5;">
    <div class="card-body p-4">
        <div data-mdb-input-init class="form-outline">
            <form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Comment" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" asp-route-returnurl="@ViewData["ReturnUrl"]">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
                <input type="Hidden" asp-for="PostId" />

                <div class="input-group">
                    <input asp-for="Content" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type comment..." required/>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

То есть я использую ModelOnly, поэтому должны подтягиваться ограничения из описания модели, в самой модели Comment прописано следующее:
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Content is required")]
public string? Content { get; set; }

Поэтому форма не должна отправляться без данных, но при нажатии на кнопку отправить, меня все равно перенаправляет на страницу Comment/Create,хотелось бы понять почему так

Покажите код контроллера
